# SolrCloud High Availability during indexing operation

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I am testing High Availability feature of SolrCloud. I am using the following setup

- 8 linux hosts
- 8 Shards
- 1 leader, 1 replica / host
- Using Curl for update operation

I tried to index 80K documents on replicas (10K/replica in parallel). During indexing process, I stopped 4 Leader nodes. Once indexing is done, out of 80K docs only 79808 docs are indexed.

Is this an expected behaviour ? In my opinion replica should take care of indexing if leader is down.

If this is an expected behaviour, any steps that can be taken from the client side to avoid such a situation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you should use CloudSolrServer to update solrcloud index.As it take cares of down nodes do not receive any update request and routes all further request to an appropriate node in the cluster.One more thing you need to ensure is all your 80k documents have unique field value, and its value is really unique across all documents